# Where do I get the "Mad Monk" mission?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-x

According to the guide, I need to be level 20 and accept "Backup Request." This is taken care of (I've beaten chapter 4 by the way.)

Regardless, I should be able to at least find the quest, and I can't. Where is it physically located?

(This is the quest to recruit Boze, by the way.)

Comment: Okay, found the supposed location at the East Gate, but it isn't there. Is there a Chapter requirement or something the guide doesn't list?

Answer (score 1):

You need to finish Chapter 5 first.